# Less hotkeys not working, printing keycodes instead performing action

Tags: linux, terminal, fedora, hotkeys, less

When I try something like

```
php -i | less
```

Less is not responding to hotkeys, but prints them like pressing "q" results in statusline

```
:q
```

PageDown

```
:^[[6~
```

Pressing ENTER like "executes" the keycode and less perfoems the action.

Piping trivial small stuff work however...

OS: Fedora 14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`php -i` is doing something weird with stdin. Try this:

```
php -i </dev/null | less
```

Comment: Actually, it's `less` that does the "something weird".  It changes to non-canonical mode input processing.  Of course `php` may well be doing something _as well_, but this is simply a specific case of the more general *don't have two programs simultaneously interacting with the terminal that employ different terminal input modes and expect things to work*.

Comment: @JdeBP: `less` may very well be doing something weird, but this is from `strace php -i` *without* `less`: `ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0`

Comment: Setting canonical mode input processing (`icanon`) is not "something weird".  Canonical mode _is the norm_.  Hence its name.

Comment: @JdeBP: Well, I don't know what's hidden behind the `...` and perhaps the clue lies elsewhere. But why is `php -i` opening stdin *at all*? It does this same odd behavior with `more` (which is not a symlink or alias on my system), but, interestingly, not `pg` or (inconsistently) `most`. PHP also does this with `php -r 'for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) { print "$i\n"; }' | less`. AWK, Perl, Python, etc., don't exhibit this weirdness. Conclusion: PHP is broken.